# Error when deploying an Android app bundle

Tags: android, deployment, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, android-update-app

In Google Play Console I'm trying to test an update for an app that was previously deployed using APKs to an app bundle.

I'm generating the APK (with build code 4) and creating a new release in the internal testing track. The upload and publishing of this version is successful.

In the second step, I'm generating based on the same codebase an app bundle (with build code 5). The upload is successful but when trying to publish the app it throws the error:

> **Error: You cannot publish an instant-enabled Android App Bundle in an installed track.**

*App versions:*
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CzZ1.png)

*The error in the review summary:*
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbYmh.png)

I would have expected to be able to upload an app bundle as an app update but the error seems to tell the contrary.

How should I proceed in order to have an app bundle as an update for an app that was so far deployed using APKs?

**UPDATE:** I'm getting the error also when publishing the app bundle as the first deployment.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle   @mihai.batista

Comment: Thank you @PınarKaraman for the resource, can you point me to the relevant section?

Comment: You're welcome , I think it will help if you examine them 
 https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/upload-bundle  @mihai.batista